# Add http header "User-Agent" to HTTP CONNECT request

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

**Prerequisites**

- Apache Tomcat 7
- Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE
- Apache Camel 2.14.1
- Camel HTTP4 Endpoint (camel-http4)

**Problem**

I try to call a https encrypted site via http4 component. 
The proxy which is in between my server and the internet (target server) checks the header "User-Agent" and rejects the request if it is empty.

The connect-Request does not contain the http header "User-Agent".

In org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec in method `private boolean createTunnelToTarget(AuthState proxyAuthState, HttpClientConnection managedConn, HttpRoute route, HttpRequest request, HttpClientContext context) throws HttpException, IOException` following is called:

```
    BasicHttpRequest connect = new BasicHttpRequest("CONNECT", authority, request.getProtocolVersion());
    this.requestExecutor.preProcess(connect, this.proxyHttpProcessor, context);
```

`this.requestExecutor.preProcess` adds header "Host" and "Proxy-Connection" to the HTTP CONNECT request but not "User-Agent".

How can I add the Header "User-Agent" to the HTTP CONNECT request?

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved in httpclient 4.4.1.

In class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder the httpprocessor is initialzed with a HttpRequestInterceptor for User-Agent:

```
    ClientExecChain execChain = createMainExec(
            requestExecCopy,
            connManagerCopy,
            reuseStrategyCopy,
            keepAliveStrategyCopy,
            new ImmutableHttpProcessor(new RequestTargetHost(), new RequestUserAgent(userAgentCopy)),
            targetAuthStrategyCopy,
            proxyAuthStrategyCopy,
            userTokenHandlerCopy);
```

The solution is to update the httpclient version from 4.3.3 to 4.4.1 .
In maven I had to define the dependency so that not the verson used by camel was choosen.